# jQuery that executes only when a child element in the parent div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element with some child controls in it (dropdowns and check boxes).

I need some jquery that will run when any of the child elements are clicked, but not when the empty space in the div is clicked.

What is the proper jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself as of yet?

Comment: Why not just target the control directly via jQuery and attach an event listener to it?  I'm confused as to how the parent div comes into play.

Comment: There are many controls in the div. I want the jQuery to act on any child element that will be in the div. Now or in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly something like this

```
$('YourDivSelector *').click(function(){
   // your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Only attaching the click to the child elements as shown by the answer of mguimard is the best approach. 
In case the contents of the div are dynamic however, you could use event.target to check if the element being clicked is the same as the element that the function is attached to as follows:

```
$('#YourDivID').click(function(e){  
  if(e.target!==this)
     console.log('child element clicked');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a children is clicked with `target.nodeName` e.x. :

```
$("#div").click(function(event) {
    console.log("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName);
});
```

Comment: Consider the following markup : `<div> <div> </div> <!-- other stuff --> </div>`, you cannot tell which div has been clicked (the parent or the child one) with the nodeName attribute